# Getting 404 on webapi call when called from HTTPClient

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

So I continue my saga  to track down this weird WebApi issue.

Our production environment is the following, 
2 windows 2012 servers with IIS 8.5 behind a load balancer.

When I hit the site directly, http://MyServer/ApiToHit/api/Values?samAccountName=someAccount&success=True&permissionName=MyPermission

I get an nice Success String.

But when hit it using a httpclient page on server 1 that points to the api on server 1, i get a 404 error page.  If i change the link to server 2, it works perfectly.

HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.

HttpClient code

```
using (var client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler { UseDefaultCredentials = true }))
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));


                var values = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(string.Format(
                    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PathToParameters"].ToString(),
                    "someAccount".ToUpper(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                    true.ToString(),
                    "MyPermission".ToUpper(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)));

                lblResult.Text = string.Empty;

                var newUrl = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Url"].ToString() + values);

                // HTTP GET
                var response = await client.GetAsync(newUrl, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead).ConfigureAwait(false);
                //var response = await client.GetAsync(values, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead).ConfigureAwait(false);
                this.lblResult.Text = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
```

Here's the api in question (shortened for the question)

```
[Authorize]
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    public string Get(string samAccountName, bool success, string permissionName)
    {
        var returnValue = "Success";

        return returnValue;
    }

}
```

route

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    // Web API configuration and services

    // Web API routes
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );

}
```

We've tried changing the web.config with

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
```

and

```
<modules>
  <remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" />
  <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" preCondition="" />
  <!-- any other modules you want to run in MVC e.g. FormsAuthentication, Roles etc. -->
</modules>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had to do things to fix this issue.

1 - Under binding in IIS, we added the server name in the hostname section for all available ip (on the server) for port 80.