# Endpoint accessible when called directly, but returns 404 when called using HttpClient

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I have a simple .Net 8 web API where one of the endpoints needs to access an endpoint on a legacy system written 10 years ago using .Net Framework 4. The legacy API is hosted on IIS 8.5, and is able to receive and process requests when called directly.

However, when I call it from my new code using an instance of HttpClient, then I get a 404 result. The code is a simple POST `var responseMessage = await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(url, request);`

Can someone please help me with pointers on how to investigate an issue like this?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you expect when we can't look at any of the code (and what you've included doesn't really help). My suggestion is to use a tool like Fiddler. Compare the raw content of the request made with `HttpClient` to the one made "directly". Possibly the server has been coded to require a "User-Agent" header.

Comment: I test `var responseMessage = await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(url, request);`with the action in the same server it works fine. Have you check this :[Getting 404 on webapi call when called from HTTPClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38640250/getting-404-on-webapi-call-when-called-from-httpclient?rq=2)?

Comment: @Qing How have you tested it in the same server when OP hasn't provided that information?

Comment: @Qing testing on the same server is much more interesting than the OP's question itself.

Comment: Hi @ProgrammingLlama , I create a web api application and test the code `var responseMessage = await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(url, request);`  to call an action in another application, and it can excute, so I guess the problem maybe about the link I provided, not cause by "call it from my new code using an instance of HttpClient" . So I suggest op can have a check. I apologize for my unclear expression.

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama unfortunately the company I work for does not allow us installing tools like Fiddler and WireShark. I actually got into trouble a few weeks ago because I did this while investigating a different issue lol

I tried setting different request headers before asking for help here, but I didn't think the User-Agent header would be significant - so I didn't try that. But I'll try set it and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: @QingGuo, I already tried the solution in the linked post before creating this one, but unfortunately it did not work.

Comment: In that case, you can probably set up a TcpListener using C#, and then capture the first message from the client (use `http` not `https`, since `https` will be encrypted).  It will be more complicated, but should get you the same information re request headers.